# Homotopy of Jordan curves

Tags: homotopy-theory, curves, plane-curves

I'm struggling with the following question:
Let $\gamma$ be a (not necessarily smooth) closed Jordan curve and let $\operatorname{int} \gamma, \operatorname{ext}\gamma$ denote the interior and the exterior respectivelly.
Is it true that $\gamma$ is homotopic to some circle in $\operatorname{ext} \gamma$? More precise:
Is there some continuous mapping
$$
H: \left[ 0,1 \right] \times \left[ 0,1 \right] \longrightarrow \operatorname{ext} \gamma
$$
such that $H(0, t) = \gamma(t)$ and $H(1,t) = Re^{it}$ for all $t \in \left[ 0,1 \right]$ and some large $R >0$?

If found this related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32734/jordan-curve-homotopy) and it seems to me that the answer to my question is given in the second comment. However I'm not able to elaborate the details.

What I know so far:
By a theorem of Caratheodory the conformal map
$$
 \phi : \lbrace \vert z \vert > 1\rbrace \longrightarrow \operatorname{ext} \gamma
$$
extends to a homeomorphism from $\lbrace \vert z \vert \geq 1\rbrace$ to $\overline{\operatorname{ext} \gamma}$.

Putting for example $H(s,t) = \phi((1 + s) e^{it})$ should transform $\gamma$ to some curve in $\operatorname{ext} \gamma$, but I don't know how the proceed.

Comment: Hint: First solve thus problem when $\gamma$ is a round circle.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Thanks for your reply. For a circle this is pretty easy, isn't it? It should be sufficient to do some affine transformation to put the origin in the middle and then just stretch it. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Now think of a composition of three maps, two of which is given by Caratheodory's theorem.